# Can anyone Optimize this code in dart. I was making Search filter for each words

Tags: firebase, flutter, search, dart, firebase-realtime-database

**I need to add search filters for firebase So that I can get search result easily and precisely**

I was altering the code from here[This Medium Post](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/implement-searching-with-firebase-firestore-flutter-de7ebd53c8c9)

```
void main() {
  print(setSearchParam("Dr apj abdul Kalam"));
}

setSearchParam(String caseNumber) {
  List<String> caseSearchList = List();
  String temp = "";
  String temp2 = "";
  String temp3 = "";

  if (caseNumber.split(" ").length > 1) {
    String firstWord = caseNumber.split(" ")[0];
    String secondWord = caseNumber.split(" ")[1];
    String thirdWord = caseNumber.split(" ")[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < firstWord.length; i++) {
      temp = temp + firstWord[i];
      caseSearchList.add(temp);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < secondWord.length; i++) {
      temp2 = temp2 + secondWord[i];
      caseSearchList.add(temp2);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < thirdWord.length; i++) {
      temp3 = temp3 + thirdWord[i];
      caseSearchList.add(temp3);
    }
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < caseNumber.length; i++) {
      temp = temp + caseNumber[i];
      caseSearchList.add(temp);
    }
  }
  return caseSearchList;
}
```

OutPuts are like List of each word letters = [D, Dr, a, ap, apj, a, ab, abd, abdu, abdul]

I am pushing these lists to firebase so that I can get search results easily...
if there is an alternative for searching in firebase, then pls let me know...

if anyone still didn't understand my question, pls look at the link I provide above.

Comment: 1. Your post would be more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. 2. Don't make identical calls to `caseNumber.split(" ")`. 2. Make a function to return a list of all prefixes for a given string, and then you don't need four copies of that code. 3. You handle `split()` returning 1 word or 3 words, but what if there are 0 words, 2 words, or 4 or more words?  Instead iterate over each word, call your helper function on each word, and merge the lists of prefixes. (Or have the helper function directly append to an existing list if you want to avoid the separate merge step.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jamesdlin also mentioned, your code can be optimized a lot.

I have tried make a more optimized version here which also will work for string of any sizes and any number of words:

```
void main() {
  print(setSearchParam("Dr apj abdul Kalam"));
  // [D, Dr, a, ap, apj, a, ab, abd, abdu, abdul, K, Ka, Kal, Kala, Kalam]

  print(searchParamWord('test'));
}

List<String> setSearchParam(String caseNumber) =>
    caseNumber.split(' ').expand(searchParamWord).toList();

Iterable<String> searchParamWord(String word) sync* {
  final sb = StringBuffer();

  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    yield (sb..writeCharCode(word.codeUnitAt(i))).toString();
  }
}
```

I have split the logic of your code into two parts.

`searchParamWord` takes one word and split it into its components like "(t, te, tes, test)" and returns a lazy evaluated iterator. This iterator can then later be used by [`expand`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/expand.html) in `setSearchParam` where we split the long `String` into each separate word.